How to create an Instant indexing plugin function for a core PHP website currently used in the WordPress platform?
WordPress platform is easy to use because of themes & plugins. Now, the Instant indexing plugin is very useful to submit newly added pages to Google Search indexing API.
Similar actions want to add in my core php html js website. But there is no plugin or something, need some custom code that automatically submits newly added sitemap pages to the indexing API.
Has anyone developed this kind of code & tested it? Is it working well or not?
I have not tried it yet, searching solution that is already available.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
